# Installing jqgrid on ASP.NET MVC (Not finding jqgrid)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

This seems like an easy problem to solve, but I've been on it for over 8 hours already with no progress so I will ask her.  I am running ASP.NET MVC 5 and I'm trying to get the jqgrid package set up.

I Keep getting the following error message when the page is loaded:

"0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'"

Here is my view:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css")

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $("#rowed5").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['ID Number', 'Name', 'Stock', 'Ship via', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
              { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 90, sorttype: "int", editable: true },
              { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 150, editable: true, editoptions: { size: "20", maxlength: "30" } },
              { name: 'stock', index: 'stock', width: 60, editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "Yes:No" } },
              { name: 'ship', index: 'ship', width: 90, editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX" } },
              { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 200, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "textarea", editoptions: { rows: "2", cols: "10" } }
            ],
            editurl: "server.php",
            caption: "Input Types"
        });
    });
</script>


    <table id="rowed5" class="scroll"></table>
```

The only thing I did different from what the install directions say to do is I put the css in a directory called content instead of css and I put the scripts in a directory called Scripts instead of js.  This should not make a difference as I reflected this in the paths when I included the libraries.

My page is having no problem locating jquery as I could use all of the normal jquery functionality.

Comment: Can you check your browser's developer tools for any problems loading any of the jqGrid files?

Comment: I'm in IE and I hit F12.  How can I tell if there were problems loading the files?  I have a console window.

Comment: My console is actually saying 0 errors and 0 warnings

Comment: Open the Network tab in the developer tools and refresh the page. Each file the browser requests will be listed along with whether or not the request succeeded.

Comment: interesting, all the js files have a 304 return code, but the jqgrid has a 200

Comment: refreshing changed it to 304

Comment: Where you includes on HTML page the fragment of the code which you posted? Typically one includes CSS and JavaScript files inside of `<head>` part. On the other side `<table id="rowed5"></table>` should be included inside of the `<body>`. Moreover you use `datatype: "local"` without any `data` option. So an empty grid will be created (if no error occurs).

Comment: I copied the grid (datatype: "local") from one of the simple examples on the web.  I just wanted to get the grid working before I customized it.

Comment: Looks like Oleg's answer worked.  I needed to make sure it was in the head section.  I added this in my master page.